# Read subset of firebase realtime database with rules restrictions

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a firebase real-time database structured like this:

```
{
  "USERS": {
    "user-1": { ... },
    "user-2": { ... }
  }
  "GROUPS": {
    "group-1": {
      "id": "group-1",
      "AUTH": {
        "user-1": true,
      }
    },
    "group-2": {
      "id": "group-2",
      "AUTH": {
        "user-2": true
      }
    },
    "group-3": {
      "id": "group-3",
      "AUTH": {
        "user-1": true,
        "user-2": true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I know that I can give read permissions that would give read access to users that only belong to a specific group, like this:

```
{ 
  "rules": {
    "GROUPS": {
      "$groupId": {
        ".write": false,
        ".read": "auth != null && data.child('AUTH').child(auth.uid).exists()"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I'm trying to find a query + rules combination that would return me all the groups that the logged in user belongs to.

For example: 
A query and firebase rule change that for logged in 'user-1' returns a snapshot of:

```
{
  "group-1": {
    "id": "group-1",
    "AUTH": {
      "user-1": true,
    }
  },
  "group-3": {
    "id": "group-3",
    "AUTH": {
      "user-1": true,
      "user-2": true
    }
  }
}
```

OR

```
[
  {
    "id": "group-1",
    "AUTH": {
      "user-1": true,
    }
  },
  {
    "id": "group-3",
    "AUTH": {
      "user-1": true,
      "user-2": true
    }
  }
]
```

querying for the "GROUPS" reference now give me a 'permissions denied' error.

adding '.read=true' to the GROUPS:

```
{ 
  "rules": {
    "GROUPS": {
      ".read": true,
      "$groupId": {
        ".write": false,
        ".read": "auth != null && data.child('AUTH').child(auth.uid).exists()"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

or any combination for '.read' that passes the condition, gives everyone access to all the data.

Is there a way (in the current structure) to query the database and get from the "GROUPS" branch all the groups that I belong to by adding some restriction to the rules? 
or do I need to maintain under each user the list of the group that he belongs to?